# Playready Envelope Format

Tags: specifications, envelope, playready

I'm trying to encrypt arbitrary content using the PlayReady envelope format, in order to send it to a 3rd party app which supports that format.

I was not able to find the format specification online.
Does anybody know where I can find the spec, or is it supported only by opaque services provided by Microsoft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the PlayReady Envelope format specified in the Microsoft PlayReady Documentation Pack (available to Microsoft PlayReady technology licensees). The relevant section is `Specifications -> Microsoft PlayReady Format Specification -> 3. Envelope File Format`.